# Pythonic way to join 3 dictionaries by a ',' and call json_dumps on each of them

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
 for dict in container:
     translated += json.dumps(dict) + ","

 translated = translated.rstrip(',')
```

I'm looking for the Pythonic way of doing this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
translated = ','.join(json.dumps(dct) for dct in container)
```

Instead of the generator expression you can also use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
translated = ','.join(map(json.dumps, container))
```

Comment: Minor tweak that's slightly more succinct and can be faster (not worth its own answer): `','.join(map(json.dumps, container))`

Comment: @ShadowRanger This is an actual occasion where `map` does make sense :) thx, added

Comment: Yar. My rule of thumb is to use `map` if there is already a single argument function that does *exactly* what you want; if not, stick with listcmp/genexpr, which will be faster and usually more readable than `lambda` based `map`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Same rule for me :) The "Pythonic" in the question, however, always has me leaning a bit further in the comp/gen direction, as those are the syntactic sugars Python beginners should really cherish.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach if `container` is JSON-able as a `list` (applies to `list`/`tuple`):

```
translated = json.dumps(container, separators=(',', ': ')).strip('[]')
```

If `container` is an arbitrary iterable, you could do:

```
translated = json.dumps(list(container), separators=(',', ': ')).strip('[]')
```

or just use [schwobaseggl's more general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46479920/364696) that's not quite such an abuse of JSON formatting flexibility.

Comment: Note: The precise `separators` used affects both the `dict` representation and the separation between `dict`s, so this is *not* 100% equivalent (differs on internal whitespace).